# How could I make something like this in javascript?

Tags: javascript

[image]

The red things are buttons.

White boxes are some inputs that I would like to process.

The first button "add": if a user presses it, the user will be able to select pictures. From PC.

If the user selected, for example, 5 pictues. The first picture must be shown. Then the user inputs stuff in the fields and when the user presses done the user is then given the next image and again fields.
On each "done" i would like to do something with those fields and image.
I'm new to JavaScript.

Comment: 1) write code 2) debug code 3) use code 4) ??? 5) profit

Comment: I dont want code, ill be fine with a tutorial or smthing to guide me in the right way..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the FileReader-API.